# Block a dashlet from getting added in sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm, dashlet

Hy Everybody!

Does anyone knows how to block a dashlet from getting displayed in modules tab which will be displayed in "Add Sugar Dashlets" window shown below:

[image]

I am using Sugar Pro 6.4.0.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow guide from here http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2011/08/11/howto-how-to-hide-a-dashlet-from-the-add-dashlets-dialog-in-an-upgrade-safe-way/